# changing the position of signs

Tags: geometry

The answer should be

y-y_{0}=k(x-x_{0})
y-(-1)=k(x-8)
y+1=kx-8k
kx-y-8k-1=0

---

But i got

kx-y+8k+1=0

Why last two minuses no need to change after transferring it to the other side?

Comment: Ummm... what is the question?

Comment: The first four lines are correct.  What you got is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You were given the point $(-8,-1)$ and not $(8,-1)$.

Comment: That might well be true but how do you know it?  Slava tells us what "the answer should be" but doesn't say what the question to be answered is!

Comment: Being nice to new contributor OP .. not difficult to see his query and sign error made.